# How to multiply integers within separate user input lists

Tags: python

Attempting to do some calculation on two separate user input generated lists. The calculation is simple, only trying to multiply the stored integer in one list with another. I'm sure this is possible but maybe I am going about this the wrong way...

```
def rackinput():
    rack_input_voltage = input('Please enter the supplied voltage to rack: ')
    rack_input_voltage = int(rack_input_voltage)
    rack_input_amperage = input('Please enter the supplied amperage to rack: ')
    rack_input_amperage = int(rack_input_amperage)
    for num1, num2 in zip(rack_input_amperage, rack_input_voltage):
        rack_wattage.append(num1 * num2)
    print(rack_wattage)
```

Comment: `rack_input_amperage` and `rack_input_voltage` are not lists. What is your question BTW?

Comment: Thanks for the help all! not sure why I was downvoted for asking this though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are trying to do this:

```
def rackinput():
    rack_wattage = []
    rack_input_voltage = list(map(int, input('Please enter the supplied voltage to rack: ').split()))
    rack_input_amperage = list(map(int, input('Please enter the supplied amperage to rack: ').split()))
    for num1, num2 in zip(rack_input_amperage, rack_input_voltage):
        rack_wattage.append(num1 * num2)
    print(rack_wattage)
```

Assuming that input output is:

```
Please enter the supplied voltage to rack: 1 2 3 4
Please enter the supplied amperage to rack: 5 6 7 8
[5, 12, 21, 32]
```

Answer (score 0):

What your're currently doing with

```
rack_input_voltage = input('Please enter the supplied voltage to rack: ')
rack_input_voltage = int(rack_input_voltage)
rack_input_amperage = input('Please enter the supplied amperage to rack: ')
rack_input_amperage = int(rack_input_amperage)
```

is getting two separate integers from the user, not lists.
If you intend for the user to give a space separated input of multiple values, then you'll have to split the resulting string and cast each element into an integer.

Like so:

```
def rackinput():
    rack_input_voltage = input('Please enter the supplied voltage to rack: ')
    rack_input_voltage = rack_input_voltage.split(" ")
    rack_input_amperage = input('Please enter the supplied amperage to rack: ')
    rack_input_amperage = rack_input_amperage.split(" ")

    rack_wattage = []

    for num1, num2 in zip(rack_input_amperage, rack_input_voltage):
        rack_wattage.append(int(num1) * int(num2))

    print(rack_wattage)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it written will throw a runtime error because `rack_wattage` is not defined.  You either need to pass it in as a method parameter or declare it in the method.

```
def rackinput(rack_wattage):
    rack_input_voltage = input('Please enter the supplied voltage to rack: ')
    rack_input_voltage = int(rack_input_voltage)
    rack_input_amperage = input('Please enter the supplied amperage to rack: ')
    rack_input_amperage = int(rack_input_amperage)

    rack_wattage.append(rack_input_voltage * rack_input_amperage)
    print(rack_wattage)
```